# Guessing function in solving functional equation

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

While solving olympiad functional equation sometime we guess the answer and to verify it we put it back in the equation.

My question is say we want $F(X)$ and I have guessed $f(x)$ as answere now in books sometime they put $F(X)=f(x)+g(x)$ and then solve for $g(x)$ and sometimes they put $F(X)=f(x)g(x)$ and then solve for $g(x)$ , I want to know how to decide what to put back in the equation.

If required I can give examples:

Here is one https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1804289p11993777
 and https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?ui=2&ik=650d20114d&attid=0.1&permmsgid=msg-f:1653993712802343065&th=16f42a84c0502899&view=att&disp=safe&realattid=16f42a7d08264c9ee8f1

also why is there at all need to take g(x) , i mean once we have guessed a function we can just put the function as it is in the equation to verify, why involve g(x) at all

Comment: There isn't really definite criteria for anything working (in olympiad functional equations) and the same is true here. In your example, I suppose the $2^{-x-y}$ motivates looking at multiplying powers of $2$ - but this shallow 'motivation' is perhaps the best answer anyone can give. Keep in mind that AOPS is a forum for sharing solutions - users generally don't describe their motivations for trying certain things, or their many pages of failed attempts before coming up with a solution that works.

Comment: I have added another problem , take a look at that one, also why is there at all need to take g(x) , i mean once we have guessed a function we can just put the fumction as it is in the equation to verify, why involve g(x) at all